# Magento Multi Store Store Code

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, store-view

We want to use one Magento backend for multiple stores and every store have normally 1 store view. We have 2 or more websites with 2 or more store views.

For German, we want to use the store code "de", for English "en" and so on. Now our problem is that every store code can't be used more than one times (is unique). When we get more websites and stores we must find for every a new store code.

Now one URL looks like this:

For a German store view, "mysite.com/deu/" or "mysite.com/de1/" and this is not fine. What can we do to solve this problem with the unique store codes?

Hope you can help me.

Comment: Why don't you use different domains for your websites so they can all have /de or /en etc?

Comment: We want only one magento backend for all stores. this is the problem.

Comment: Its not a problem! :) You can use multiple domains for different websites or store views in magento, all using the same admin. Just enter the new domain where you would normally specify the base url after selecting your website scope in the top left of the admin. System > Configuration > web, i think.

Comment: But with this we can use the store code only one time

Comment: That's fine, you're store code doesn't have to be the same as your url. so just use store1-de and store2-de, or similar. The store code must be unique

Comment: I know this question is quite old but I assume this workaround should still work on Magento 1.9.x and maybe also on Magento 2.x I've tried to rework the above, but now I always get 404 errors when switching the language. What i try to achive is using identical language codes for several stores in a multi store setup but default shop shouldn't have an language code. In URLs it looks like this: www.first_store.com www.first_store.com/en/ www.first_store.com/fr/ www.second_store.com www.second_store.com/en/ www.second_store.com/fr/ ... What I've done:
I've created an website folder in magento roo

Answer (score 2):

here is what I did in a similar case.
Let's say you have 2 websites with 2 store view each.  both website have a EN and a DE store view (codes can be anything).

First create 2 folders in the root of your magento install with 2 subfolders each.

- website1

  - en
  - de
- website2

  - en
  - de

Then copy `index.php` and `.htaccess` into `website1`, `website1/en`, `website1/de`. Do the same for `website2` and its subfolders.

Now edit `index.php` from all the folders and subfolders like this:

`website1/index.php` and `website2/index.php`

replace `$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php';` with `$mageFilename = '../app/Mage.php';`  and

```
Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

with

```
 Mage::run('website code here for each website', 'website');
```

Then in the `index.php` of each of the `de|en` folders
change `$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php';` to `$mageFilename = '.././app/Mage.php';`

and

```
Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

to

```
 Mage::run('each store view code here', 'store');
```

Now remove the `Show store codes in url` flag.

In `System->Configuration->web->unsecure` set the these values

- `Base Skin URL` : `http://example.com/skin/` instead of `{{unsecure_base_url}}skin/`
- `Base Media URL` : `http://example.com/media/` instead of `{{unsecure_base_url}}media/`
- `Base JavaScript URL` : `http://example.com/js/` instead of `{{unsecure_base_url}}js/`

Do the same for the secure section if you are using secure urls just put `https` instead of `http`.

Now you have to create 2 virtual hosts, one for each website.
The document root for the first website will be `website1` folder and for the second one `website2`.

If you want you can create only one folder `website1` but this means that you have to create the `en` and `de` folders in the root folder of your magento instance for the second website and your second website has to have the document root, the root of your magento instance.